# Downloading data, creating core data object and then using those to make next request

Tags: ios, core-data

I am struggling to come up with an elegant solution to a problem involving multiple network requests. If you need further information than what has been provided then please don't hesitate to ask.

I need to download data from a server, create core data objects from it and then use information from those objects to download the next set of data. So I am transversing a hierarchy.

So for example:

- I make my first request to the server and pull down the Regions which is made up of 4 objects (North, South, East, West). I am saving these to core data.
- Once that is done (not sure best way to track this) I then need to do a fetch request on the region entity to get back those 4 objects. Each region contains a number of counties which I need to request from the server. So I loop through the regions and make a network request for each region.
- I loop through each returned dictionary (one for each region) to create each county.

Here is my code to download the regions and county:

```
    + (void)downloadRegions
    {
        NSString *search = @"organisation";

        NetworkHandler *networkHandler = [[NetworkHandler alloc] init];
       [networkHandler downloadData:search];
    }

    + (void)downloadCounty
    {
       NSManagedObjectContext *context = [DatabaseHandler sharedHandler].managedObjectContext;
       NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

       NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Region" inManagedObjectContext:context];
       [request setEntity:entity];

        //NSPredicate *searchFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"attribute = %@", searchingFor];
       NSError *error = nil;
       NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
       NSLog(@"%@", results);

       NSString *search = @"organisation?code=";

       for (Region *region in results) {
            NSString *s = [search stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", region.code]];
            NetworkHandler *networkHandler = [[NetworkHandler alloc] init];
            [networkHandler downloadData:s];
       }
    }
```

Both of the above methods call:

```
- (void)downloadData:(NSString *)searchUrl
{
    NSString *apiURL = [kBaseURL stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"api"];
    NSString *finalURL = [apiURL stringByAppendingPathComponent:searchUrl];

    self.dataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:finalURL]
                                             completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                                 NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

                                                 //self.jsonData[searchUrl] = json;

                                                 [self createObjectInDatabase:json andSearchURL:searchUrl];

                                                 NSLog(@"This has been reached");
                                             }];

    [self.dataTask resume];
}

- (void)createObjectInDatabase:(id)data andSearchURL:(NSString *)searchURL
{
    if ([searchURL isEqual:@"organisation"]) {
        [Region createNewRegionWithData:data inManagedObjectContext:[DatabaseHandler sharedHandler].managedObjectContext];
    }
    else {
        [LAT createNewLATWithData:data inManagedObjectContext:[DatabaseHandler sharedHandler].managedObjectContext];
    }

}
```

I am not sure if I am doing this the best way. In regards to making the request, creating the object and then making the next request.

My biggest issue is knowing when to make the next request. i.e - knowing when the download has completed and all the core data objects have been created successfully before making a request for those objects and using them in the next request. I am currently making the second request manually but need it to be done automatically.

I hope that is clear. I am finding it hard to explain :-). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you passed a string into `downloadData:` that the completion handler then used to post a notification as it was finishing?  When you receive each notification, you know which step of the process to go to next.

Comment: Hi Philip thanks for the response. When I am downloading the counties I have to loop through a certain amount of regions which might not stay consistent. I.e an extra region maybe added in future. Do you have any suggestions on how to track when each set of counties for each region has been downloaded and created in core data?

Comment: If you go the notification route, you can add either a single object or an entire "userinfo" dictionary to the post.  One of those could describe the downloaded information.

Comment: Thanks. I am also using the string to track what data is being download so I can call the correct create method for core data. 2 birds one stone :-)